# c# how to validate all ConfigurationElement properties upfront?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have several custom configuration elements (classes derived from ConfigurationElement), some of the properties have validation attributes, other are of enum types.

The problem is that the configuration object can be created correctly, but only when accessing a property an exception is thrown. (In this case, string does not parse to any known enum value).

My question is, can I somehow make sure at the program startup that there are no problems with any of the custom sections in my app.config file before I proceed?

Thanks, Radek

Comment: You can load each of your custom sections at application startup and validate them. Either they'll throw an exception when you try to load them or if they contain some other value that you determine is invalid.

Comment: The problem is that an exception will now be thrown until you try to access a particular property of the custom section. So it's not so easy, unless there is a trick to do it in more automated way.

Comment: You could mark up the custom configuration classes with [data annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx) and validate them. Even if the validations don't do anything I think it would force access of the properties which in turn would get your exception thrown up front.

Comment: I tried marking the configuration class with one of very few data annotation attibutes which can be applied to the class (ScaffoldTableAttribute) but no, it didn't help. Still class is read but properties are validated only when accessing them.

Answer (score 1):

Given this sample `ConfigurationSection` that contains an `enum`:

```
public class MyConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty(name: "myProperty")]
    public TestEnum MyProperty => 
        (TestEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(TestEnum), Convert.ToString(base["myProperty"]));
}

public enum TestEnum
{
    A = 1, B = 2
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="myConfigurationSection" 
             type="ValidatedConfigurationSection.MyConfigurationSection,
                   ValidatedConfigurationSection"/>
  </configSections>

  <myConfigurationSection myProperty="NoSuchValueInEnum"/>
</configuration>
```

this will throw an exception if an `enum` value is invalid (requires `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.)

```
private void ValidateSection(object section)
{
    var context = new ValidationContext(section);
    Validator.ValidateObject(section, context);
}
```

No validation attribute on the object itself is required.

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks a lot :)
I passed the entire custom section object as a "section" parameter and all properties are validated recursively including collections as well. Perfect!